# Segment lengths from perpendicular projections to next vertex

Tags: geometry

I will set a competitive programming task for a local contest. The problem is as follows:

Given a regular polygon with $n$ sides and a random point $P$ inside the polygon, we will draw $n$ perpendicular projections from this point to the $n$ polygon sides. Denote the point of intersection of the $i$th projection and the corresponding polygon side as $p_i$. You are given the length of each segment from $p_i$ to the next ccw polygon vertex, denoted as $a_i$. Calculate the polygon side length $s$.

Examples for an equilateral triangle and a pentagon are shown in these images:

[Equilateral Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1IA4.png)

[Regular Pentagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcuYV.png)

The solution is given:

> $s$ = $\frac{2 \sum_{i} a_i}{n}$
>
>  Proof Hint: Divide each zone into two right triangles.

I need to ensure that each test case gives valid values for all $a_i$. I already have one restriction on the values which is $0 < a_i < s$ because we can't have a length greater than $s$. Otherwise, the projection will be outside the polygon.

For example, an invalid test case is $n = 3$ and $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 100$, $a_3 = 1$. In this case $s = 68$.

Are there any additional important restrictions I need to apply on $a_i$ to ensure that each case is valid ? For example, are there any lower/upper bound on the sum of two consecutive values / total sum of $a_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly are additional restrictions. The placement of $P$ inside the polygon has only two degrees of freedom. It is completely determined by $a_1$ and $a_2$. Therefore the remaining $a_i$ can be computed once you decide on the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

But you may have some difficulty setting integer values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ so that the remaining values are integers when $n > 4$.

Note also that the solution is relatively trivial for even $n$.
The projection lines from $P$ form $n/2$ concurrent lines, each of which cuts opposite faces into two $a_i$ values that naturally add up to $s$.
So the answer is just $a_{n/2} + a_n$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! $P$ can be uniquely determined from only $a_1$ and $a_2$. However, I can't think of a way to validate (or calculate) $a_3$ .. $a_n$ other than computing each vertex of the polygon (considering that the first is at [0,0]) and then checking these distances (which will need a lot of computation). Is there another way to validate the lengths?

Comment: There must be a way to use the regularity of the polygon to guide the computation of the other lengths given $a_1$ and $a_2$, but I don't see an obvious way to make it really simple.

Comment: I will transform the question to the following:
Given the coordinates of $P$, calculate $a_x$ $(3 \leq x \leq n)$ .

How this could be solved other than calculating the polygon vertices?